# error : identifier "__func__" is undefined with ICC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, icc

I'm trying to compile my project with Intel's C++ Compiler but I'm getting many errors like these:

```
1>..\src\luascript.cpp(5889): error : identifier "__func__" is undefined
1>          reportErrorFunc(getErrorDesc(LUA_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND));
1>          ^
```

I've compiled this project with MS Visual Studio before and got no warnings or errors but with ICC I get this. Here is the section of code that produces that error

```
int32_t LuaScriptInterface::luaNetworkMessageAddItem(lua_State* L)
{
    // networkMessage:addItem(item)
    Item* item = getUserdata<Item>(L, 2);
    if (!item) {
        reportErrorFunc(getErrorDesc(LUA_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND)); //This is the line that the error points to
        lua_pushnil(L);
        return 1;
    }

    //...
}
```

The definition `reportErrorFunc` is:

```
#define reportErrorFunc(a)  reportError(__FUNCTION__, a, true)
```

There is also:

```
#ifndef __FUNCTION__
#define __FUNCTION__ __func__
#endif
```

Please let me know if you need me to post anymore code

I'm on Windows 7 SP1 x64 with MSVC 2013 Ultimate and Intel C++ Studio XE 2013 SP1 U2

Comment: The problem is presumably in the definition of the `reportErrorFunc` macro.

Comment: @Barmar Its defined like this: ```#define reportErrorFunc(a)  reportError(__FUNCTION__, a, true)```

Comment: Keep expanding macros -- something must have `__func__` in it.

Comment: @Barmar In my definition there is this: ```#ifndef __FUNCTION__
#define __FUNCTION__ __func__
#endif```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of Intel XE the `__func__` predeclared identifier may or may not be available. Make sure you use `/Qstd=c++11` to enable its availability.

More information is availble at:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler

Comment: There is no `func` keyword. `__func__` is like a special variable.

Comment: @chris ugh i forgot to quote it, fixed.  the markdown takes `\`__strong__\`` as a strong as in `__strong__` becomes  __strong__ without the `\`\``

Comment: I didn't even think about that.